# Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file but no encoding declared

Tags: python, encoding, signal-processing, non-ascii-characters

I wrote a script to extract signals from the MIT-BIH dataset using the [wfdb](https://github.com/MIT-LCP/wfdb-python) python library. The script was working fine when I was running it on ***windows*** but I recently shifted to ***Mac***. After installing all the dependencies I got an error when I tried to import ***processing*** from the ***wfdb*** library. This is the error I get:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py on line 3346, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

import wfdb works fine but there seems to be a problem when I do `from wfdb import processing`. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: You should maybe consider updating to Python 3, support ends for Python 2 in 2020

Answer (score 3):

Please add following line at the top of the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Also, avoid using non-ascii quotations.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to copying and pasting code from web which causes stray byte floating. You can find it by running.

```
with open('my_script.py', 'r') as ms:
    for i, line in enumerate(ms):
        if '\xe2' in line:
            print(i, repr(line))
```

And the line and its index value will be printed where there is '\xe2':

```
4, "\xe2        word=string.printable(random.randint[0,61]) # Gets the random word"
```

**Note: You should replace my_script.py with your respective .py file.**

Answer (score 0):

This was due to a scipy [bug](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/9606) which has been [fixed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/9615).