# Handle UnicodeEncodeError in python2.7

Tags: python, string, unicode, character-encoding

I have the following code :

```
    for index, row in df_out.iterrows():
        yield {
               'CustomerName': str(row['CustomerName'])
              }
```

and I get the the UnicodeEncodeError:

```
RuntimeError: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I handle this part in order to avoid that error?

```
str(row['CustomerName'])
```

Comment: copying and pasting of code causes **\xe9** so avoid it. [Check This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54388973/non-ascii-character-xe2-in-file-but-no-encoding-declared/54389155#54389155)

Comment: @SantoshKarki I'm not copying/pasting code

Comment: Then check above link

Comment: @SantoshKarki The post you linked is about non-ASCII characters in the source code. The OP is dealing with an encoding problem in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are potentially dealing with non-ASCII text in python2, then doing

```
str(some_text)
```

is usually bad idea, because you will get a `UnicodeEncodeError` if `some_text` contains non-ASCII characters. The correct code would be

```
unicode(some_text)
```

as `unicode()` will not try to encode your text as ASCII.

However given this code

```
for index, row in df_out.iterrows():
    yield {
           'CustomerName': str(row['CustomerName'])
          }
```

it's very likely that `row['CustomerName']` is *already*  a `unicode` object, so calling `unicode` on it would be redundant.  This will probably work:

```
for index, row in df_out.iterrows():
    yield {
           'CustomerName': row['CustomerName']
          }
```

To summarise: remove the `str` call.  If that doesn't work, try replacing `str` with `unicode`.